# How to add input values in table from a form in different page using React.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sqlite, backend

I am new to React.

I am working on a react project that has a table on the home page, which shows the data of different people. My goal is to add the person details from a form present on a different page into this table.

My future goal is to add these values in a database(sqlite3) for permanent storage and also display these details in the table present.

The table should add multiple rows each time the user fills the form.

App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Link, NavLink, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

    import SignUpForm from "./pages/SignUpForm";
    import SignInForm from "./pages/SignInForm";
    import AccountPage from "./pages/AccountPage";
    import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";

    import "./App.css";

    class App extends Component {

    render() {
    return (
    <Router basename="/react-auth-ui/">
    <div className="App">
      
      <div className="App__Form">
        <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignInForm}></Route>
        <Route path="/HomePage" component={HomePage}></Route>
        <Route path="/AccountPage" component={AccountPage}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/" component={SignUpForm}></Route>
        
        
      </div>
      </div>
      </Router>
      );
      }
      }

      export default App;
```

SignUpForm.js

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
   import HomePage from "./HomePage";

   class SignUpForm extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
   super(props);

    this.state = {
 
    name: "",
    weight: "",
    height: "",
  
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

   handleChange(e) {
   let target = e.target;
   let value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
   let name = target.name;

   this.setState({
   [name]: value,
   });
   }

   handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   this.props.history.push('/HomePage');
   console.log("The form was submitted with the following data:");
   console.log(this.state);

   }

   render() {
   return (
   <div className="FormCenter">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="FormFields">
      <div className="FormField">
      <div className="heading">
        
          <h2>Project</h2>
        
      </div>
      
          <div>
          <h1>Enter Person details</h1>
          </div>
          <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="name">
          Full Name
          </label>
          <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          className="FormField__Input"
          placeholder="Enter your full name"
          name="name"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
           />
          </div>

       
          <div className="FormField">
          <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="weight">
          Weight
          </label>
          <input
          type="number"
          id="weight"
          className="FormField__Input"
          placeholder="Enter your weight"
          name="weight"
          value={this.state.weight}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
           />
          </div>

          <div className="FormField">
          <label className="FormField__Label">Height</label>
          <input
          type="number"
          id="height"
          className="FormField__Input"
          placeholder="Enter your height"
          name="height"
          value={this.state.height}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
      
          </div>

         <div className="FormField">
          <button className="FormField__Button mr-20">Add Persont</button>{" "}
        
        
           <Link to="/HomePage" className="FormField__Link">
            Back
          </Link>
           </div>
          </form>
          </div>
           );
           }
           }

           export default SignUpForm;
```

HomePage.js

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import SignInForm from "./SignInForm";
    import SignUpForm from "./SignUpForm";
    import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
    import * as ReactBootStrap from "react-bootstrap";

    class HomePage extends Component {

    onSub = () => {

    this.props.history.push('/');

    }


    render() {

    const name = this.props.name;
    const weight = this.props.weight;
    const height = this.props.height;

    return (
  
    <div className="FormCenter">
   
       <div className="heading">
        
          <h2>Project</h2>
        
        </div>
        <div className="FormField">
          <div>
              <h1>Welcome Rahil</h1>
              <h2>Person Details</h2>
               
          </div>
          <div>
          <table>
            <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Weight</th>
          <th>Height</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>rahil</th>
        <th>122</th>
        <th>6</th>  
        </tr>  
        <tr>
        <th>{name}</th>
        <th>{weight}</th>
        <th>{height}</th>  
        </tr>  
        
      </tbody>
      </table>
          </div>
      </div>

     
      

      <div className="FormField">
        <button className="FormField__Button mr-20" onClick={this.onSub}>
          Add new Patient
        </button>{" "}
        <Link to="/sign-in" className="linkForm" style={{color:"white", textDecoration:"none"}}>
          Logout
         </Link>
        
         </div>
    
         </div>
          );
          }
          }

          export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal you need to manage the state of your application. When you want to manage the state within your whole application (having different pages for filling in the data and showing the data) you should implement a state management library like Redux or use the React Context API.

With the state management library you can implement the Provider pattern into your application. This allows you to split your logic from the ui and manage the state very efficient.

Redux:
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts#why-should-i-use-redux

React Context API:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

There are many more state management libraries but these two are very popular. Just check which fits best for your needs in terms of complexity.